# What is the probability of rain?

Tags: stardew-valley

I am wondering if anyone knows what the chance of rain is in Stardew Valley, whether per season or just in general. I know it doesn't in the Winter.

I was not able to grab the Pendant in the rain because I was not at 10 hearts with anyone yet, but now (Spring Year 2, Day 8), I have 10 hearts with 4 people because I haven't been able to buy the Pendant; simply because it has not rained since the second day of Fall.

**Update**: It is the 25th of Spring, Year 2, and since the start of the game, I have a total of 6 rain falls. (2 in Spring Year 1, 2 in Summer Year 1, 1 in Fall Year 1, and now finally 1 in Spring Year 2).

Am I just unlucky or are there just super low chances of rain in the Fall/Early Spring?

Comment: I'm not sure of the chances exactly.  It may be different for every game, as the game takes advantage of the Unique game ID to do some of its calculations.  You can craft a [Rain Totem](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Rain_Totem) which boosts the changes of rain happening the day after you use the totem.

Comment: I figured it might do that, but wasn't sure if there was a general percentage or something that was known. And I'm still a level of foraging off from that totem :(

Comment: I would keep cutting trees down to get foraging up and then make the totem.  Maybe you'll get lucky and it will rain one of the days while you try to level up foraging.  Hopefully winter doesn't come before then, as the Mariner won't spawn in winter!

Comment: I hope it doesn't go a full year without rain.. that'd be annoying. And I'm hoping maybe someone knows something about this anyway just for curiosity sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/49426s/stardew_valley_beta_branch_v105_bugsdiscussion/d0s31ok/) it seems as though it's something that has been known since the game was first released. Ape responded and didn't seem to know why it was happening. Many other discussions also have people who claim to have rain for most of the year, while others have next to none all year. There do not seem to be many instances of an even balance, such as rain once or twice a week.

Which leads to a [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/48ti13/please_fix_the_random_number_generation/) like this one which discusses the random number generation that Stardew Valley supposedly uses. It seems as though the system is not the best and it can be pretty skewed for something like rain. While sometimes the numbers could be statistically normal, they can be unlikely or not preferred. However, at this time it does not seem as though there is any sort of change coming.

Which then leads to the only current solution as, suggested by @Timmy_Jim (and found on a few other sites), to use Rain Totems to boost the chance, and hopefully overcome the poorly generated chance of rain.